# EasyAdmin 4 Symfony 6 dropdown field shows only one class type extending the InheritanceType one

Tags: symfony, inheritance, crud, easyadmin

The applicant is the base class:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ApplicantRepository::class)]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'type', type: Types::STRING)]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    ApplicantType::COMPANY->value => Company::class,
    ApplicantType::PERSON->value => Person::class,
])]
abstract class Applicant
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: UuidType::NAME)]
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'NONE')]
    protected AbstractUid $id;
```

The Service class has following property:

```
 #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Applicant::class, cascade: ['persist'], inversedBy: 'services')]
 #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
 private Applicant $applicant;
```

Then in the ServiceController

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            AssociationField::new('applicant', t('backoffice.performances.APPLICANT')),
            ...
```

The result is that in the form pages of the `ServiceController`, the `Applicant` dropdown shows only `Person` entities instead of showing `Company` ones too.

The `id` of the `Applicant` is protected as suggested in some GitHub issues, but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add the class form type option as follows:

```
AssociationField::new('applicant', t('backoffice.performances.APPLICANT'))
  ->setFormTypeOptions([
     'class' => Applicant::class
  ])
```